# How does Linux kernel handle threads calling sleep or pause?

Tags: linux-kernel, signals

According to Linux man page, the thread calling sleep or pause can be woken by a not ignored signal. And I learned that there is a so called "sleep queue" in Linux.

1. Does that mean the kernel has to check each thread in the "sleep queue" to see whether there is a pending signal that can be handled?
2. I know a process can be stopped by SIGSTOP. Is a stopped thread also in the "sleep queue"?
3. When there are multi threads in a process. Mix signals and sleep may cause great trouble?

Comment: I think you should do a step back (so looking the system). The kernel will send the signal, so no need to check about pending signals. When kernel has a signal it will just check how to handle it (and moving processes in the active scheduler). So let's an event to wake up a process (and because the event is direct to a process, we know which process to wake up). So you will see that your problems are non-existent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's reasonable.